# How I can break the div after each loop of insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually each time I press the button it should show some thing like in facebook chat box to show new message but instead on each click the new message does not go in the downward but instead it comes next to it.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#im_chat').click(function() {
        var a = $('#im_textarea').val();

        alert("It is working!!!!");
        $('#im_popup')
            .append($('<p CLASS="well well-sm" id="msg"></p>')
            .css('margin', '10px')
            .css('display', 'inline-block')
            .text(a));
    })
})
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `display: inline-block;`, just show each message in a `<div>` or any other element displayed as a block :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#im_chat').click(function() {
    var a = $('#im_textarea').val();
    var $message = $('<div />')
      .css({
        margin: '10px'
      })
      .text(a);
    $('#im_popup').append($message)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="im_popup"></div>
<textarea id="im_textarea"></textarea>
<div>
  <button id="im_chat">Send</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but with out it I will not be able to fit the size of div withrespect to the content of the div

Comment: I want to make a small div like fb chat messages div

Comment: Then you should set a fixed width you the messages container which is `#im_popup` in your case